# Access parent view button in recycler.vew adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have one button in main activty.i want to access that button id in recycler.view adapter.how can i do this?

Comment: I think you need to explain more about your problem

Comment: That's a bad approach to access button in recyclerview adapter. Rather than if you want to performa any operation, just give callback to your Activity from Adapter and BAMM you are done ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below line of code

```
        ((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.yourButtoId)
```

Comment: Can u just explain.actually i want to change parent button according to adapter checkbox view selection.

Comment: What you want to change in the button. In above code get the context and cast that to the activity because you can call findViewById() metthod with activity reference and then pass the id you are interested to get

Comment: I have a checkbox in recycler adapter.when i check that button should enable ,if checkbox not selected button should disable

Comment: hmm ok use above code that will give you the view of the button and then cast that view to the button (by this you can perform button specific tasks) and then use setVisibility method and done

Answer (score 3):

Try this .

**MainActivity**

```
public View getButton() {
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    return btn;
}
```

**Use in your adapter**

```
((MainActivity) getContext()).getButton();
```

Comment: new MainActivity() creating object for activity ?? activity is based on context i think it is better to get activity from context.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.@rajahsekar